# Find the inverse of the following function.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Define $A = \{1,2,\cdots, N\}$ and $B= \{1,2,\cdots, N^2\}.$ Then consider the function
$f:A\times A \to B$ such that 
$$f(i,j) = N(i-1)+j.$$

I observed that we can write that 
$$j \equiv f(i,j)\pmod{N}$$
and so we can write that 
$$i = \frac{f(i,j)-j}{N} + 1.$$
However, the problem is that taking the modulo with respect to $N$ we push $j$ to the set $\{0, 1, \cdots, N-1\}$ which is not good.

Comment: The new fangled computer think insists upon one fixed set of charteristice values modulus N.  Since 0 = N (mod N) the problem vanishes except for the new fangled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is:

$ j = (k-1)\pmod{N} + 1$ and $i = \lfloor(k-1)/N\rfloor+1.$